# R calculating average purchase price

Tags: r

I just started learning R (really, only a day of experience) and I'm currently trying to migrate an SQL code to R just to see how they compare.

One of the use cases is calculating average stock purchase price. Now in my data I have transactions with negative and positive volume, and only + volume is used to calculate avg. On the other hand, the average purchase price is needed at rows with - volume, as that is later used to calculate profit/loss of that sales transaction.

A sample data could be constructed like this:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20)*10, nrow=10))
df$X3 <- df$X2 * df$X2
```

then I have a function which calulates avg:

```
avgPurchasePrice <- function(volume, eurPrice){
  price <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(volume))
  s=0
  t=0
  for(i in 1:length(volume)){
    if(volume[i]>0){
      price[i] <- volume[i]*eurPrice[i]+t;
      volume[i]<-volume[i]+s;
      s <- volume[i];
      t <- price[i];
    } else {
      volume[i] <- s;
      price[i] <-t;
    }
    volume[i]=price[i]/volume[i];
  }
  volume
}
```

and average is calculated as

```
df$avgPrice <- avgPurchasePrice(df$X1,df$X3)
```

Question: is this approach OK? I don't know R and there might be better ways / patterns to implement this, as this approach seems very "traditional"

Edit:

In words I think it should be: for each positive volume, calculate average (buy) price as ratio of total price over total volume; for negative volume use the last value without changing it

I've looked into dplyr and came up with this (which only works on my data file)

`stock %>% group_by(FINANCIAL_INSTRUMENT) %>% mutate(                                                 cumPrice=cumsum(vol=ifelse(VOLUME>0,VOLUME,0L)*PricE),                                                cumVol=cumsum(ifelse(VOLUME>0L,VOLUME,0L)),
                                                     cumPrice/cumVol)`

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to do this with less effort in terms of code. You could try the R-package `dplyr`, where you get e.g. an idea of how to calculate means. Look at this vignette http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html Aside from that, there are basic solutions. Also have a look at this page http://www.statmethods.net/management/aggregate.html

Comment: Are you sure your formula is correct? Can you please describe in words how you are calculating this average?

Comment: Right now I'm not even concerned about it being 100% correct, but rather learning the patterns. I added more information in the original post above and looked into dplyr as @rmuc suggested.

Comment: In your loop, if the first volume is negative, you assing to `volume[1]` the value of `s` (which is zero in case `i=1` and `volume[1] <0`) and then divide `price[1]` by `volume[1]`, hence by `0`...

Comment: A good point, but in a sample that I have volume is always non-zero

Comment: So did the `dplyr` solution solve your problem or not? If not, what exactly isn't working? Also, when replying to people, please use `@` and their name afterwords, otherwise they don't see your replies.

Answer (score 1):

This is the original code with little improvements and the equivalent solution to dplyr with native R code

```
set.seed(323)
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20)*10, nrow=10))
df[,2]=abs(df[,2])
colnames(df)<-c("Volume","Price")
#df$EurPrice <- df$Volume * df$Price
avgPurchasePrice <- function(volume, eurPrice){
    price <- vector(mode="numeric", length=length(volume))
    s=0
    t=0
    avpr=vector()
    for(i in 1:length(volume)){
      if(volume[i]>0){
        price[i] <- volume[i]*eurPrice[i]+t;
        volume[i]<-volume[i]+s;
        s <- volume[i];
        t <- price[i];
      } else {
        volume[i] <- s;
        price[i] <-t;
      }
      avpr[i]=price[i]/volume[i];
    }
    avpr
  }
#average
df$avgPrice <- avgPurchasePrice(df$Volume,df$Price)

df$avgPrice2<-cumsum(ifelse(df$Volume>0,df$Volume,0)*df$Price)/cumsum(ifelse(df$Volume>0,df$Volume,0))
df
```

> ```
>        Volume      Price avgPrice avgPrice2
> 1  -5.332687  2.0293922      NaN       NaN
> 2  12.148825  3.8633988 3.863399  3.863399
> 3   7.528894  1.3639138 2.907071  2.907071
> 4   2.158501  6.1042484 3.223110  3.223110
> 5   8.886568 13.2210598 6.115018  6.115018
> 6   7.884685 13.7922340 7.682912  7.682912
> 7   1.436665  8.9700328 7.729090  7.729090
> 8  -2.235569  2.0624435 7.729090  7.729090
> 9   8.707973  0.2852434 6.399490  6.399490
> 10  3.924928  1.0760426 6.002844  6.002844
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `PMwR` (Portfolio Management with R). You need to create a journal in its terms with unit price, net amount (buy/sell), stock name and date.

My example is below:

```
Stocks_j <- journal(timestamp = c(Stocks$Date),
                    amount = c(Stocks$Net),
                    price = c(Stocks$Unit_price),
                    instrument = c(Stocks$Stock))
```

Then a profit/loss function seems to calculate all you need:

```
pl(Stocks_j)
```

Example stock outputs:

```
#STOCK_1 
  P/L total          NA
  average buy   29.3676
  average sell  40.3341
  cum. volume      1635

#STOCK_2 
  P/L total     339.955
  average buy     19.45
  average sell   50.355
  cum. volume        22
```

The details of the package can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PMwR/PMwR.pdf).